# Catboost building and installing error in R

Tags: r, catboost

Having problems with the proxy, I try to install catboost for R from a local copy in Windows following [this instruction](https://tech.yandex.com/catboost/doc/dg/concepts/r-installation-docpage/#local-copy-installation-windows).

The only difference is that I didn't download catboost repo via gitbash but manually via the website.

I've installed python and add it to the path.

I've installed  **Visual Studio Community 2017**, with Windows Platform development and Desktop Development with C++ options.

I've installed also VC++ 2015.3 v140 toolset for desktop (x86,x64) and VC++ 2017 v141 toolset (x86,x64) options.

No problems nor warning until here.

Then I set the working directory to the catboost R-package. Then use devtools to build and install the package.

Here I have the following warnings with build:

```
> devtools::build()
"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-34~1.4/bin/x64/R" --no-site-file --no-environ --no-save  \
  --no-restore --quiet CMD build  \
  "C:\Users\xq.do\Downloads\catboost-master\catboost-master\catboost\R-package"  \
  --no-resave-data --no-manual 

* checking for file 'C:\Users\xq.do\Downloads\catboost-master\catboost-master\catboost\R-package/DESCRIPTION' ... OK
* preparing 'catboost':
* checking DESCRIPTION meta-information ... OK
* cleaning src
Warning: C:/Users/xq.do/AppData/Local/Temp/RtmpCaOZOZ/Rbuild1f043c9b6da4/catboost/man/catboost.train.Rd:56: unknown macro '\t'
Warning: C:/Users/xq.do/AppData/Local/Temp/RtmpCaOZOZ/Rbuild1f043c9b6da4/catboost/man/catboost.train.Rd:56: unknown macro '\t'
Warning: C:/Users/xq.do/AppData/Local/Temp/RtmpCaOZOZ/Rbuild1f043c9b6da4/catboost/man/catboost.train.Rd:56: unknown macro '\t'
Warning: C:/Users/xq.do/AppData/Local/Temp/RtmpCaOZOZ/Rbuild1f043c9b6da4/catboost/man/catboost.train.Rd:56: unknown macro '\t'
* checking for LF line-endings in source and make files and shell scripts
* checking for empty or unneeded directories
* building 'catboost_0.7.2.tar.gz'

[1] "C:/Users/xq.do/Downloads/catboost-master/catboost-master/catboost/catboost_0.7.2.tar.gz"
```

and the following errors with install:

```
> devtools::install()
Installing catboost
"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-34~1.4/bin/x64/R" --no-site-file --no-environ --no-save  \
  --no-restore --quiet CMD INSTALL  \
  "C:/Users/xq.do/Downloads/catboost-master/catboost-master/catboost/R-package"  \
  --library="C:/documents/xq.do/Documents/R/win-library/3.4" --install-tests 

* installing *source* package 'catboost' ...
** libs
  running 'src/Makefile.win' ...
/cygdrive/c/Users/xq.do/Downloads/catboost-master/catboost-master/catboost/R-package/src/../../../ya.bat make -r -o ../../..
ERROR: <urlopen error timed out>
ERROR: <urlopen error timed out>
ERROR: <urlopen error timed out>
ERROR: <urlopen error timed out>
ERROR: <urlopen error timed out>
ERROR: <urlopen error timed out>
make: *** [all] Error 1
Warning: l'exécution de la commande 'make --no-print-directory -f "Makefile.win"' renvoie un statut 2
ERROR: compilation failed for package 'catboost'
* removing 'C:/documents/xq.do/Documents/R/win-library/3.4/catboost'
In R CMD INSTALL
Error: Command failed (1)
```

Here is my R session information:

```
> session_info()
Session info ----------------------------------------------------------------------
 setting  value                       
 version  R version 3.4.4 (2018-03-15)
 system   x86_64, mingw32             
 ui       RStudio (1.1.442)           
 language (EN)                        
 collate  French_France.1252          
 tz       Europe/Paris                
 date     2018-04-06                  

Packages --------------------------------------------------------------------------
 package   * version date       source        
 base      * 3.4.4   2018-03-15 local         
 compiler    3.4.4   2018-03-15 local         
 datasets  * 3.4.4   2018-03-15 local         
 devtools  * 1.13.5  2018-02-18 CRAN (R 3.4.3)
 digest      0.6.15  2018-01-28 CRAN (R 3.4.3)
 graphics  * 3.4.4   2018-03-15 local         
 grDevices * 3.4.4   2018-03-15 local         
 memoise     1.1.0   2017-04-21 CRAN (R 3.4.4)
 methods   * 3.4.4   2018-03-15 local         
 stats     * 3.4.4   2018-03-15 local         
 tools       3.4.4   2018-03-15 local         
 utils     * 3.4.4   2018-03-15 local         
 withr       2.1.2   2018-03-15 CRAN (R 3.4.4)
 yaml        2.1.18  2018-03-08 CRAN (R 3.4.4)
```

Comment: I see four warnings, but where is the error?

Comment: @dash2 I've updated the question.

Answer (score 2):

I also face some issues when installing CatBoost using devtools for the first time. So, these are what I did back then:

1. Download the CatBoost latest version from [here](https://github.com/catboost/catboost/releases).
2. Install the file using `install.packages()`. Try something like this:

   `install.packages("C:/Users/AnastasiyaRomanova/Downloads/catboost-R-Windows-0.18.1.tgz", repos = NULL, type = "source", INSTALL_opts = c("--no-multiarch", "--no-test-load"))`

The above steps work well for me. In some cases, you must rename the file extension from `.tgz` to `.tar.gz` to avoid an error.

Comment: This (extension rename) also has worked for me. I had an error: > 
  Arguments in `...` must be used. I managed to manually download the package, rename the extension to .tar.gz and then install with command: install.packages("C:/R_packages_files/catboost-R-Windows-1.1.1.tar.gz", repos = NULL, type = "source", INSTALL_opts = c("--no-multiarch", "--no-test-load"))

Answer (score 1):

The Yandex team have made R packages available. They should update their R instruction pages.

You can download and install version 0.7.2 package for Windows as follows:

```
devtools::install_url('https://github.com/catboost/catboost/releases/download/v0.7.2/catboost-R-Windows-0.7.2.tgz', args = c("--no-multiarch"))
```

This downloads the package from the [releases page.](https://github.com/catboost/catboost/releases) When there is a new version, just change the version numbers in the url and download the new version.

Answer (score 1):

Install CatBoost for R

```
# install.packages("devtools") 
library(devtools)
devtools::install_github('catboost/catboost', subdir = 'catboost/R-package')
```